# How can I run a JavaScript function by taking user input & using a button?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<title> Daily Recommended Exercise </title>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Your Daily Exercise Schedule</h2>    

<p>Please select your age group:</p>

<form>

0 - 5: <input type = "radio" name = "PickAge" value = "Age1">
<br/>
6 - 17: <input type = "radio" name = "PickAge" value = "Age2">
<br/>
18 - 64: <input type = "radio" name = "PickAge" value = "Age3">
<br/>
65 - 150: <input type = "radio" name = "PickAge" value = "Age4">
<br/>

<input type="button" onclick = "exerciseRecommend();" value = "Enter"></input>

</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function exerciseRecommend()
{
var age = document.getElementsByName("PickAge");

if (age=="Age1")
{
    alert("Physical activity in infants and young children is necessary for     healthy growth and development. There are no guidelines for children at this age      though regular physical activity is recommended.");
}
else if (age=="Age2")
{
    alert("At this age you should do 60 minutes or more of physical activity each day. This includes, aerobic endurance and strength exercises.");
}
else if (age=="Age3")
{
    alert("At this age you should be doing two hours and thirty minutes or more of moderate aerobic endurance and strength exercises activity every week OR one hour fifteen minutes of intense aerobic endurance and strength exercises activity OR a mix of the two.");
}
else if (age=="Age4")
{
    alert("At this age you should be exercising 2-3 hours a week. It is recommended that you should be doing mild endurance and strength activities.");
}
}

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

What is wrong with this code? Whenever I press the button nothing happens!! I have tried again and again but for some reason it is not finding the user input and outputting any alert values! Please help!

Comment: You are comparing an array of DOM elements to strings, so your function will do nothing. Aside from that, it would help if you put your entire script in an onload event handler and attached the event listener to the button through JS itself. That is just a best practice to assure that your functions are initialized before you attach them to DOM objects.

Answer (score 0):

Shashank is correct that best practice is to attach the event listener through JS itself, but in your case I'll assume that you're learning the language and just want to know what's up and how it works.

So, let's take a look at your `age` variable.  If you `console.log(age)` after you define it, it will return a Node list of all of the elements with the name "PickAge".  What you want is a specific one of those, the checked one.

```
//  Get a list of all the select-able ages
var allAges = document.getElementsByName("PickAge");
//  Define a variable that will hold our selected age
var age;

//  Iterate through all of the select-able ages
for (i = 0; i < allAges.length; i++) {
    //  If the selected age is checked, set it to the "age" variable
    if (allAges[i].checked === true) {
        //  We grab only the value here because that's what you check later
        age = allAges[i].value;
    }
}
```

That should give you the correct result that will work with your if < alert.  You might want to add an else statement at the end in case the user doesn't select any age, though.

Just to make sure you know, this isn't best practice, efficient, or the best way of doing this.  This is just a quick example to help you understand the process a bit to help you get the basis for the language.